# I want to count set bits of binary number of any given number. But the range of given number can vary to 10^200

Tags: java, binary, biginteger

I want to count set bits of binary number of any given number.

But the range of given number can vary to  10^200.

I tried using BigInteger and converted bigInteger to binary string using num.toString(2);

But maximum range of string is 2^31.

Any idea what else I can use here.

Comment: The maximum **length** of a String is 2^31 - 1 (`Integer.MAX_VALUE`). That means your method can handle BigIntegers as large as 2^Integer.MAX_VALUE, which is about 10^646456993. So please show your code and explain what isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

A `BigInteger` can be converted to a `byte[]` using `BigInteger.toByteArray()`. You can then iterate over the `byte[]` and count the set bits in each byte using code found here:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-set-bits-in-an-integer/

Note that `int` can be replaced with `byte` in that example.

Answer (score 0):

There's `bitCount()` method you can use for that:

```
    // So, we create a big number
    BigInteger num = new BigInteger("10");
    num = num.pow(200);

    System.out.println(num.bitCount());
```

Just for fun, you can test that it gives you the correct number:

```
    String binaryNum = num.toString(2);

    System.out.println(binaryNum);
    System.out.println(binaryNum.chars().filter(c -> c == '1').count());
```

Comment: `.chars()` requires Java 9+.

Answer (score 0):

The maximum range of a `String` in `Java` is `2^31 - 1` is true but it's not about the Maximum value of a number it can hold, it is about the **Number of characters it can contain.**

That said, you don't need BigInteger to find the number of set bits in a number (Even for a large number), just remember the way to find Binary representation of a number.

Ex:

```
2|12|0
2| 6|0
2| 3|1
2| 1|-
```

So from the above, we know that the binary representation of 12 is `1100`.
We can easily calculate the number of set bits if know the binary representation of a number.

Coming to the problem, you know that you can't handle that big into a number, so use a string to store the number and perform the above method.

To divide a number that is stored in a string start dividing the part of the number from the start,i.e., the most significant digit of the decimal number.
Check whether it propagates a carry to the right, you can do this by a simple `&1` which tells about the LSB of those digits.
Finally, count the number of set bits with b.

```
public class Expelliarmus{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String a = "9000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000";//88 zeroes, you can test it for other numbers too
        System.out.println(fn(a,0L));
    }

    static long fn(String a, long b){ // Don't ask why I used long here
        if(a.length()==0) return b;
        if(a.length()==1 && a.charAt(0)=='1') return ++b;
        int n = Integer.parseInt(a.charAt(a.length()-1)+"");
        if((n&1)==1) ++b;
        a = divideMe(a);
        return fn(a,b);
    }

    static String divideMe(String a){
        int val = 0;
        String bb = "";
        for(int i=0;i<a.length();i++){
            int dup = 0;
            val = val*10 + Integer.parseInt(a.charAt(i)+"");
            if((val&1)==1) dup = 1;
            val = val/2;
            bb = bb + String.valueOf(val);
            val = dup;
        }
        if(bb.charAt(0)=='0') return bb.substring(1);
        return bb;
    }
}
```